# Number of firms in the market

Tags: economics

Suppose market for corn is in long-run equilibrium. All suppliers face same cost curve $AC=300-q+0.02q^2$. The demand curve is given by: $D(P)=642,000-36P$. How many firms are there in the market ?

I'm getting no idea how to do it. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Is there a negative after $AC$ or should there be an $=$ sign?

Comment: Does $AC$ denotes the average cost function or the function for the total cost ?

Comment: Yes, $AC$ denoted average cost function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The long-run competitive equilibrium price equals the minimum average total cost.

We find the quantity produced by each firm at the minimum average cost by solving the first-order condition
$$
\frac{\mathrm d AC(q)}{\mathrm d q}=-1+0.04q=0\quad\Longrightarrow\quad q=25
$$
Then plug this quantity into the average total cost equation to get the equilibrium price:
$$
P=AC(25)=300-25+0.02\times (25)^2=287.5
$$
At this price, the quantity demanded in the market is
$$
D(287.5)=642,000−36\times 287.5=631,650
$$
So, the number of firms is
$$
N=\frac{\text{market output}}{\text{firm output}}=\frac{631,650}{25}=25,266
$$